# Floated layouts - items running up-down-up-down, rather than side-to-side?

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, draggable, horizontal-scrolling

When floating elements *(list-items for example)* they go side-by-side, then wrap onto the next line when there isn't enough space (width) left in the container.

I was wondering is there a way, where the floated list-items/div's could display on top of each other. So groups of 2 are floated alongside each other, like in **example 2** below, example 1 being the norm:

[image: Floated layouts]

The frame in my wireframe is the viewport, as my layout will run off screen and scroll horizontally.

I'd like to do this without wrapping everything 2 items in a containing div if I can. Like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

And not with items 1 + 2 wrapped in a div and the same for 3 + 4 and so on - with the parents divs floated alongside each other.

My end goal is to create a layout like this, which is horizontally draggable rather than with a scroll bar:
[image: Website layout - horizontal scrolling]

I've made a Codepen here: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/OVapeK

The drag works ...when all the content fits on the screen. But as soon as the divs are cropped in the viewport when attempting to drag the layout it jumps around. If your monitor isn't wide enough, you can check this by reducing the number of `<figure>`'s and/or alternating the width set on the container `.project-list` - another problem I need to solve!

Thanks, hope someone can help!

**EDIT**

I've actually forked a version of my Codepen where I have the columns set up using css-columns and centred: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/waQNyM

I've set `[role="main"] {overflow: hidden;}` which hides the horizontal scroll bar. The content is draggable but doesn't behave as expected.

Also after initiating a 'drag', a top value is set inline so it kinda messes up the responsiveness/centre alignment.

Comment: Have you tried css columns? That should give you exactly what you want, though you will have to omit supporting browsers that do not support CSS columns (older IE). You will have to specify the column count, but since I guess the number of elements will be dynamically determined, you will need some JS to apply this as an inline style. http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLVgKV

Comment: I was thinking about that @connexo, was actually going to mention it in my post but I must of forgotten. This is definitely seems like a possible solution, as I don't have anyone to bounce ideas off here I thought I'd see if there are any solutions based around floating elements for older IE but I appreciate there mightn't be and css-columns might be the way to go!

Comment: I've just updated my post with a Codepen: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/waQNyM. This uses CSS columns to create the desired layout and scrolls horizontally - drag is a bit borked at the moment though!

Answer (score 0):

`flex-flow: column wrap` can do it

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    height:200px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    background-color: green;
}
        
.flex-container > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
   <div>7</div>
   <div>8</div>
</div>
```

[image]

It is a modification  of Example 1 in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-align-flexbox-columns-left-and-right-using-css